# Theme resources for universal apps

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I'm porting a windows phone 8 app to universal windows store. 
What is the proper way to replace the static theme resources from wp8 (like PhoneFontFamilyNormal, PhoneFontSizeNormal, PhoneAccentBrush).
Is there a similar list of themes on window universal apps so I could override these values or do I need to manually change all the styles? Thank you.

```
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The resource names are a bit different on 8.1.

e.g.

```
FontFamily="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}"
Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}"
```